# Does CGP deployment manager support data store as a resource

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-deployment-manager

I check the supported resource type and only find cloud storage on the list.

If not, any straightforward way to implement it?

May be it can be supported using the type provider? Please provide some insights, appreciate the help